# Backbird has killed RDP on Windows 10 (Event ID 226)

Tags: rdp

Today I've did... well, a stupid thing. I was so annoyed with Windows telemetry and its consumption of my resources, and dozens other similar sht (thank you Microsoft!), that I've ran [Blackbird](http://www.getblackbird.net/) to solve the things for me. It probably did the trick, but since then I cannot RDP from this PC anymore - I'm always getting some authentication issue:

"An authentication error has occurred. The function requested is not supported."

Windows event log (Applications and Services Logs / Microsoft / Windows / TerminalServices-ClientActiveXCore / Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDPClient/Operational) shows the following warnings (all with Event ID 226):

```
RDPClient_SSL: An error was encountered when transitioning from TsSslStateHandshakeStart to TsSslStateDisconnecting in response to TsSslEventStartHandshakeFailed (error code 0x80004005).

RDPClient_TCP: An error was encountered when transitioning from TcpStateFrontAuth to TcpStateFailure in response to TcpEventFrontAuthFailed (error code 0x80090302).

RDPClient_TCP: An error was encountered when transitioning from TcpStateExpectingX244CC to TcpStateFailure in response to TcpEventErrorProcessingX224CC (error code 0x80004005).
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this, and get RDP running again?

Bit more info: RDP client successfully initiates communication with the server (it is not a connection issue), prompts me for credentials, and fails with mentioned error when it tries to authenticate.

Thanks!

Comment: Restore from last backup - remember serverfault is a site for professional sysadmins who backup routinely and test those backups routinely.

Comment: Well yep, it is a solution. But I hoped to resolve RDP without undoing everything Blackbird did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've came to the answer I was seeking for, and I'll share it here. First I have to admit that it was my fault in the first place - I didn't read the documentation :(

It turned out that everything done by Blackbird can be undone (reverted back) (as [documentation](http://getblackbird.net/documentation/) explains) by using `-r` switch. (I haven't tried this!)

Anyway, it is always a good idea to create at least restore point (if not full backup) before doing anything with Blackbird (or any other similar app in that matter).

Finally I can say that I've successfully got rid of Cortana and telemetry by executing:

```
blackbird -kc -kf
```

Everything else seems to work fine so far.

Btw. Cortana can be also disabled in Local Group Policy (as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10#answer-951895)) without using any tool (without Blackbird).

Comment: Tried `blackbird -r`, worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Running:

```
blackbird -l
```

will fix RDP without removing any of the other fixes.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer