# Cannot establish a remote desktop connection to Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: remote-desktop-services

A Windows server has suddenly stopped accepting remote desktop connections.
When I try connecting with `MSTSC.EXE` it reports `An Internal error has occured` and with `RDCMAN.EXE` it reports `[Unknown disconnection reason 4]`.

As, domain admin, I have connected into the server successfully using `psexec \\SERVER cmd` and I can see that the 'Remote Desktop Services' service is running, and the server is listening on TCP port 3389:

```
C:\>sc query termservice
SERVICE_NAME: termservice
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0


C:\>netstat -ano | findstr  LISTEN | findstr :3389
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1640
  TCP    [::]:3389              [::]:0                 LISTENING       1640
```

What can I try, other than rebooting the server?

Comment: Most likely due to this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093492/credssp-updates-for-cve-2018-0886-march-13-2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, run command 'qwinsta` (this is a synonym for QUERY SESSION).
Check if the output is as follows:

```
C:\>qwinsta
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
>services                                    0  Disc
 console                                     1  Conn
                                         65536  Down
```

Note that against ID 65536 it says DOWN.

In that case, run the following command, as Administrator.

(if using PSEXEC, see the advice here: "[Psexec “run as (remote) admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816663/psexec-run-as-remote-admin)”)

```
C:\>reset session 65536
If you reset this session, all users using this protocol will be logged off,
continue (n=no)? y
```

Now, check with 'qwinsta' again, and it should show ID 65536 as LISTEN.

```
C:\>qwinsta
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
>services                                    0  Disc
 console                                     1  Conn
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen
```

..and then the server should start responding to remote desktop connections.

It may also be worth mentioning, that if you see just this:

```
C:\>qwinsta
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
>services                                    0  Disc
 console                                     1  Conn
```

..then remote connections may well be disabled. Check the registry to confirm:

```
C:\>reg query "hklm\system\Currentcontrolset\control\terminal server" | findstr DenyTS
    fDenyTSConnections    REG_DWORD    0x1
```

fDenyTSConnections set to 0x1 indicates 'Remote Desktop disabled' and 0x0 indicates 'Remote Desktop enabled'.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be related to Windows Updates 03-04.2018 (client 
 updated but not the server) check answer here: [RDP error "The function requested is not supported" after enabling NLA](https://serverfault.com/questions/729818/rdp-error-the-function-requested-is-not-supported-after-enabling-nla)
and this [MS info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4093492/credssp-updates-for-cve-2018-0886-march-13-2018)

Comment: You should add some relevant quests from the links to your answer.